# Compatibility Query for inserting null values in datefield

Tags: mysql, oracle

I'm using Oracle and MySQL database in our project. So we are trying to write common queries for both databases.

I'm trying to insert a date in a date field into both database tables. Both databases support this date format only: `2013-07-19`. In the course of our DML operations we are facing a problem when inserting dates as Empty or Null.

Both databases have their own syntax to store an "empty field" in a Date field/column.

MySQL allows dates as `0000-00-00` or `NULL` (specifically written at an appropriate position). But Oracle does not support this format. Oracle only allows date fields as `Empty`.

How to write common queries in this type of situation?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, both will allow NULL for date fields...? Could you describe what you need with a concrete example?

Comment: After full stop sign, you start a new sentence with a space character followed by uppercase letter. You don't randomly uppercase words of your own choice in the sentence, it makes it slow to read. You don't use multiple question marks, one is enough, more than one makes you look illiterate. I feel terrible for being a grammar nazi but seriously, this is really awful to read. It shows 0 respect  towards people you're asking to help you.

Comment: INSERT INTO TABLENAME(DATEFIELD)VALUES(''). It allows only in oracle database.The above query in mysql,INSERT INTO TABLENAME(DATEFIELD)VALUES(NULL).How to over come this situation.How to write common query for both db.

Comment: @N.B. Agreed, the same way one does not speak with one's mouth full. Call me nazi too if you like.

Comment: Fixed. Now I can upvote the question :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO TABLENAME(DATEFIELD) VALUES(NULL);
```

...works both in [MySQL](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ded7a0/1) and [Oracle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ded7a/1), so you could use that.